# c share memory dynamic matrix

Tags: c, unix, memory, shared

I'd like to share by memory a struct with a dynamic matrix composed by a rational, but i can't. Here there are the functions i'm using for create a shared dynamic matrix. They doesn't create memory for the mat[i][j] inside the matrix and, of course, i got a SIGSEGV error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "matrix.h"
#define ord 2

key_t keyArray[] = { 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128 };

void 
err_sys(const char *s) {
    perror(s);
    exit(-1);
}   

void *
shmmalloc(key_t key, uint byteSize) {
    key_t shmid;
    void *ptr = NULL;
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, byteSize, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
        err_sys("shmget");
    if ((ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1)
        err_sys("shmat");
    return ptr;
}

Matrix *
shmMatrixCreate(key_t key, int x, int y) {
    int i, j;
    Matrix *m = (Matrix *) shmmalloc (key, sizeof (Matrix));
    m->mat = (Rational ***) shmmalloc (key, sizeof (Rational **) * x);
    if (m->mat == NULL) 
        err_sys("Se acabo la memoria D: ");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        m->mat[i] = (Rational **) shmmalloc (key, sizeof (Rational *) * y);
        if (m->mat[i] == NULL) {
            perror("Se acabo la memoria D:");
            exit(-1);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) 
            m->mat[i][j] = (Rational *) shmmalloc (key, sizeof(Rational));
    }
    m->m = x;
    m->n = y;
    m->flag = false;
    return m;
}

Matrix *
shmMatrixReceive(key_t key) {
    key_t shmid;
    Matrix *ptr = NULL;
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(Matrix), 0666)) < 0)
        err_sys("shmget");
    if ((ptr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (Matrix *) -1)
        err_sys("shmat");
    return ptr;
}
```

here's the matrix struct

```
typedef long long int lli;

typedef struct matrix {
    int m, n;
    Rational ***mat;
    bool flag;
} Matrix;
```

and the Rational

```
typedef long long int lli;

    typedef struct rational {
        lli a, 
            b;
    } Rational;
```

When i do

```
Matrix *a = shmMatrixCreate(keyArray[0], ord, ord);
printf("%lld \n", a->mat[0][0]->a);
```

i got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0TYh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOLZ8.png)

Please help!

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: the posted code contains two instances of `typedef long long int lli;`

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to have to guess as to what header files were actually included?

Comment: Show us the SEGV backtrace.

Comment: the function: `err_sys()`  is not a standard C function.  And it is not defined in the posted code.  Are you expecting us to guess as to the contents of that function?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: the function: `shmget()` returns an `int`, not a `key_t`.   The function: `shmat()` first parameter is an `int`, not a `key_t`

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate contents or usage (or better, both). names like `x`, `y`  are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: in the definition of `struct matrix` is this field: `Rational ***mat;`  Suggest you read: [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: i implementer err_sys

Comment: the posted code contains: `#define ord 2` but that name `org` is not used in the posted code.

Comment: @ÁngelLópezManríquez,  The function: `err_sys()` is being called by the posted code, so it needs to be part of the posted code

Comment: i already put the function in the screenshot

Comment: regarding: `        if (m->mat[i] == NULL)
        {
            perror("Se acabo la memoria D:");
            exit(-1);
        }`  When this function is called, there may (or may not) be some shared memory allocated.  So before calling `exit()`, each of the currently allocated shared memory pointers needs to be passed to `shmdt()`

Comment: do not post links to screen shots.  post the actual text as an edit to the question.

Comment: this kind of statement: `typedef long long int lli;` and the use of `lli` in the definition of a struct;  adds nothing to the code, and just makes it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: the type name: `uint` is not defined anywhere in the posted code (and not defined in the header file: `stdint.h`)

Comment: when generating `key_t` values, do not hard code them.  rather use the function: `ftok()`  Then the proper (read/write/execute) access will be setup.  Otherwise, the code will (most likely) be unable to access the hared memory

Comment: sorry for the screenshots, i already add stdint.h but it keeps in the same error. I didn't know about shmdt()

Comment: before we can determine the cause of the seg fault event, we need to have code that we can (cleanly) compile and run.  The posted code fragments do not contain the needed information  please post a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, i'm new here jaja
do you want the code? you can get it here 

https://github.com/Ang3lino/Sistemas-operativos/tree/master/practica%206

problems are in 7.c